Jetpack Compose state changes not cause recomposition at the beginning
I saw the following code snippet in the Jetpack Compose official documentation, it demonstrates a performance issue called "backwards writes" which will cause recomposition to occur on every frame, endlessly.
My question is not related to backwards writes. I'm just confused about why infinite repeated recomposition is triggered by a click, but not at the beginning when the app runs?
Is it because compose is not ready to listen to state changes at the beginning?
@Composable
fun BadComposable() {
    var count by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    Button(onClick = { count++ }, Modifier.wrapContentSize()) {
        Text("Recompose")
    }

    Text("$count")
    count++
}

